# Does the prisoner dilemma have a non-pure strategy Nash equilibrium?

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I would like to know whether this Prisoner Dilemma has a non-pure strategy Nash Equilibrium:

[here](https://www.facebook.com/socialtheory/photos/v%C4%9Bz%C5%88ovo-dilema-je-jedn%C3%ADm-z-typ%C5%AF-hry-s-nenulov%C3%BDm-sou%C4%8Dtem-v-tzv-teorii-her-p%C5%99edsta/1743728405715283/) is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure strategy is considered a special case of a mixed strategy, so it technically has a mixed strategy of playing defect with probability one and cooperate with probability zero. However there is no non-pure mixed strategy Nash equilibrium in a prisoner's dilemma because both players have strictly dominant strategies. Any possible mix with a positive weight on cooperating would be strictly dominated by a pure strategy of defecting.